# Migrating from Oracle CTL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, migration, ctl

I would like to migrate from Oracle to MySQL, and one of the important steps is to replace the actual job built on an Oracle environment.

Basically, every day I receive some 'oracle' dump files from another Oracle environment (mainly CTL or Oracle table exports). Today my Oracle jobs loaded the received data (CTL...) in my Oracle tables. Now I would like to replace my Oracle tables in MySQL tables, continuing to receive the file coming from the Oracle environment.

So. Do you have same tools or artifacts to read the Oracle CTL files (or
Oracle tables dump) from an MySQL environment? 
I already used the mysqlimport GUI, but it does not meet my needs. I need the script/command to do these.

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781975/how-do-i-convert-oracle-database-to-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Nothing comes to mind - you may need to write custom export/import scripts - for example, to write CSV files from Oracle and to load MySQL from these CSV files... or a job that talks to both...

Although [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=mysql+import+from+oracle+export&meta=) does come up with some cross-db import/export tools - it is probably worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, from dev.mysql.com, try the MySQL Migration Toolkit:

[MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)