# How do I convert an Oracle database to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-migration

Is there a recommended tool to convert an Oracle database including ([stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)) into MySQL?

Comment: @user720210 - If you're looking for a simple tool that you can just run, I don't think you'll find one. Oracle is much more complicated, powerful, and expensive than MySQL and can't necessarily be simplified down with the push of a button. You'll probably need to create a new database in MySQL that's as similar to your oracle database as you can make it and then port whatever code/data you need to to run on the new system.

Comment: I can't think of any automated way to do such a task. You will need to rewrite all procs manually and make sure they still have the same results, mysql and Oracle have very different flavors of SQL and there is no easy way to convert as far as I know. Even if you used an automated tool, you would have to test each proc becuase an automated tool would probably not get all changes correct for complex queries such as those in procs.

Comment: Similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479500/migrate-from-oracle-to-mysql/11774222#11774222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217373/backupformat-to-transfer-data-between-different-databases) and from the answers I got I can recommend [OmegaSync](http://www.spectralcore.com/omegasync/), although I did not try to migrate stored procedures, but it's supported too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the MySQL forums: [How to migrate database from Oracle 10g to MySQL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,233895,233970#msg-233970)

You will need a MySQL administrator, or specifically Navicat (MySQL GUI).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to investigate the [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html). It claims to be able to migrate from Oracle, but it has reached its [EOL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/EOL#Initialism). I am not sure if it can help you if you're using the latest versions of Oracle or MySQL. It's replacement is [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the open source business intelligence software [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/). I suppose it supports MySQL too.

Comment: No more open source.